# Updating user table in database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've created a members area where a user can update their bio. The problem is that the information the user submits isn't updating the rows in the database.

**Member's Area**

```
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
<a href="logout.php"><button>Log Out</button></a><br><br>
<input type="text" name="age"placeholder="Enter a your age."><br>
<input type="text" name="bio"placeholder="Enter your bio.">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit your details!">
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","****","****");
  // Check connection
  if (mysql_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $age = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['age']);
  $bio = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bio']);
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);

  mysql_query($con,"UPDATE accs SET age='.$age.' WHERE name='.$name.'");
  mysql_query($con,"UPDATE accs SET bio='.$bio.' WHERE name='.$name.'");

  mysql_close($con);
};
?> 
</body></html>
```

Any Ideas as to what is wrong here?

Comment: Session open? Do you have value $name, before doing the mysql_query()?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

in your HTML page, the form should be inside the `<form></form>` tags

```
<form method="post" action="update.php">
<input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Enter a your age.">
<br>
<input type="text" name="bio" placeholder="Enter your bio.">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit your details!">
</form>
```

In your PHP page - to check the results, you can temporarily `echo $age; echo $bio;`
As you are using `$_SESSION['username'];` I think you are missing `session_start();` to the top of your PHP code.

Also `mysql_query` only needs the SQL command, and not the connection (`$con`), that is mysqli, which is strongly advised to use instead of mysql_*.

As a side note, don't rely on user names in your database as the update criteria. If not already introduced, you can add an ID column to your table

Answer (score 0):

a) create a proper submit form. use form tags around your form fields.

b) check, that the form is correctly submitted, by checking the $_POST array.

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

c) check, that you have values for the fields that you want to insert.
do a var_dump() before mysql_query(), to see what's going on.

```
var_dump($age, $bio, $name);
```

d) combine your two query calls into one:

```
mysql_query($con, "UPDATE accs SET age='.$age.', bio='.$bio.' WHERE name='.$name.'");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the page it self to process your request, then empty the action property of your form. For example :

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="age"placeholder="Enter a your age."><br>
<input type="text" name="bio"placeholder="Enter your bio.">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit your details!">
</form>
```